# To select all pages after this in Pagesel?

Tags: pagesel

You can select pages by `pagesel` like this

```
\usepackage[2-3]{pagesel}
```

However, I would like to set some *pagesel* command after some content and have everything after it in the document.
For instance, assume you have 777 pages in your document and it is time-consuming to find the page number for the selection.
If there was ending -tag for the selection, it would be great. 
I want to compile the hole document but include only some pages.

### Some features in Werner's answer

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267555/13173
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcommand{\handlethispage}{}
\newcommand{\discardpagesfromhere}{\let\handlethispage\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}
\newcommand{\keeppagesfromhere}{\let\handlethispage\relax}
\AtBeginShipout{\handlethispage}

\begin{document}
Treatment

\discardpagesfromhere
\section{1. Digestive }

GERS. 

\keeppagesfromhere
\subsubsection{Model}


\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

where the section *Digestive* and word *GERS* are removed as features in the body.

How can you include only some pages in the pagesel -process?

Comment: About draft management, one possible relevant answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35592934/54964

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can discard pages on-the-fly using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi)'s `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}\sloppy
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcommand{\handlethispage}{}
\newcommand{\discardpagesfromhere}{\let\handlethispage\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}
\newcommand{\keeppagesfromhere}{\let\handlethispage\relax}
\AtBeginShipout{\handlethispage}
\begin{document}

\discardpagesfromhere
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\keeppagesfromhere
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Above I've defined `\discardpagesfromhere` to discard pages from that point onward, while `\keeppagesfromhere` keeps the pages from that point onward.

Note that this removes any references on the discarded pages.

---

If you're sticking with [`pagesel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) and want to use page-references, you could follow this trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}\sloppy

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\@newl@bel}[3]{\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}% Update \newlabel-related macro
\input{\jobname.aux}% Read .aux file
\xdef\keeppagesfromhere{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\r@keepfromhere}% Grab page of label keepfromhere
\endgroup
\makeatother

\usepackage[\keeppagesfromhere-]{pagesel}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\label{keepfromhere}
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

We read in the `.aux` file after updating the `\@newl@bel` macro to create a reference *locally*. Then we only capture the page reference of a specific label: `keepfromhere` (this is achieved using `\expandafter\@secondoftwo\r@keepfromhere`). We use this page reference to provide a range that `pagesel` can use.

Note that you have to compile the document with `\label{keepfromhere}` before you can use it, since the label needs to exist (in the `.aux`). You could use [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to intervene and provide a page number of `0` if the label doesn't exist.

Moreover, note that `pagesel` by default doesn't update the `.aux`, so a compilation *without* `pagesel` (but with `\label{keepfromhere}`) is somewhat necessary before you can successfully discard the proper pages.

---

Of course, if you know the page number `X` from which you want to keep content, `pagesel` provides

```
\usepackage[X-]{pagesel}
```

Comment: I found some bugs in your commands `\keeppagesfromhere` when using first `discard` and then `keep`. I will update the body of my question for showing this.

Comment: @Masi: The code you use works as expected. If the content you want to remove resides on the same page, then `\discardpagesfromhere` would have no effect, as it's overwritten by `\keeppagesfromhere`.

Comment: How can you have the reverse of the `\discardpagesfromhere`? I would like to discard pages which come before the tag. Is that possible?

Comment: @Masi: `\AtBeginDocument{\discardpagesfromhere}` and then place `\keeppagesfromhere` where you want to start keeping them... have you tried that?

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\discardpagesfromhere}` can only be used in preamble. How to make it a command?

Comment: @Masi: `\discardpagesfromhere` is the command.

Comment: Yes, but I want to discard pages coming before the command. So I want to discard pages in the head and tail, without using the command `\keeppagesfromhere`.

Comment: @Masi: Why not just use `\discardpagesfromhere` ... `\keeppagesfromhere` ... `\discardpagesfromhere`?

Comment: Because I think differently. Too many steps in such a logic. You should need only two steps in doing a subset.

Comment: @Masi: The logic would be the same, it would just be hidden in two macros from the end-users perspective.

Answer (score 4):

See the answers of Werner and touhami for more elegant solutions.

For completeness, a version with `pagesel` and absolute page numbers in labels via package `zref`. Normal labels only store the page number of the page counter, but the page counter might be reset by `\pagenumbering` (`\mainmatter`, ...). Absolute page numbers are provided by package `zref-abspage`. These numbers are needed by package `pagesel`.

The `.aux` file with the labels is read via package `zref-xr`, because the normal reading of the `.aux` file comes too late in `\begin{document}`, when the packages should already be loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{zref-abspage,zref-xr}
\makeatletter
% Mark pages with tags
\newcommand*{\maketag}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{tag-#1}{abspage}%
}
\newcommand*{\maketagfirstpage}{\maketag{first}}
\newcommand*{\maketaglastpage}{\maketag{last}}

% The `.aux` file contains the labels with the page numbers.
% When the `.aux` file is read in `\begin{document}` it is too late
% for loading a package. Therefore, the `.aux` file is first read
% as external `.aux` file, where the label names are prefixed with
% "self".
\zexternaldocument[self-]{\jobname}
\edef\pageselfirstpage{\zref@extractdefault{self-tag-first}{abspage}{0}}
\edef\pagesellastpage{\zref@extractdefault{self-tag-last}{abspage}{0}}
\ifnum\pageselfirstpage=0 %
  \typeout{Warning: Missing first page for pagesel!}%
  \let\pageselfirstpage\@empty
\fi
\ifnum\pagesellastpage=0 %
  \typeout{Warning: Missing last page for pagesel!}%
  \let\pagesellastpage\@empty
\fi

% Patch for atbegshi
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\AtBegShi@Output}{%
  \@PackageWarning{atbegshi}{Ignoring void shipout box}%
}{%
  \begingroup
    \csname set@typeset@protect\endcsname
    \@PackageWarning{atbegshi}{Ignoring void shipout box}%
  \endgroup
}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand\AtBegShi@Output could not be patched}}
\makeatother

% Load package pagesel
\usepackage[\pageselfirstpage-\pagesellastpage]{pagesel}

\begin{document}
  \part{First part}
  \blinddocument   

  \newpage
  \part{Second part}
  \maketagfirstpage 
  \blinddocument    
  \maketaglastpage  

  \newpage
  \part{Third part}
  \blinddocument   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newbox\mtbox
\newenvironment{nopdf}{%
\def\shipout{\deadcycles=0\setbox\mtbox=}}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\begin{nopdf}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{nopdf}
\lipsum[1-15]
\begin{nopdf}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{nopdf}
\lipsum[1-15]
\begin{nopdf}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{nopdf}
\end{document}
```