# How to print out only statements (theorems, lemmata, etc) from a tex file?

Tags: formatting, packages, theorems, preview

Suppose that I have a long tex file with a lot of things. In order to read the logic structure only, I want to print only text inside \begin{theorem}..\end{theorem} and \begin{lemma}..\end{lemma}.

Sure, I can embrace all the other parts incide something like \show{...} and then define \show[1] as %1 when I want to see all content and as {} if I want to see only statements.

But I am looking for a more elegant solution. =) Something like the preview package http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/preview/preview.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `atbegshi` and `answers` packages.

The idea is to use `answers` that write contents of theorem, lemma to an external file (mtfile.tex), discard all pages (all contents of the main file https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267555/71471) and then use the external file to output only theorems.

We use a newif test `\onlytrue` for only theorem and `\onlyfalse` for normal use.

Auxiliary environments used to save the original definitions of `theorem` and `lemma`.

```
\newtheorem{xtheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{xlemma}{Lemma}
```

Complete code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcommand{\handlethispage}{}
\AtBeginShipout{\handlethispage}

\newtheorem{xtheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{xlemma}{Lemma}

\newif\ifonly % uncomment next line
%\onlytrue   
\ifonly
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{lemma}{mtlemma}{mtfile}
\Newassociation{theorem}{mttheorem}{mtfile}
\renewenvironment{mttheorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\renewenvironment{mtlemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}
\Opensolutionfile{mtfile}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\handlethispage\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}
\AtEndDocument{%
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}
\let\handlethispage\relax
\Closesolutionfile{mtfile}
\Readsolutionfile{mtfile}}
\else
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\newenvironment{lemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}
\fi


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{lemma}
this is some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{theorem}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{lemma}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's wickedly clever. The only solutions I could come up with, are much more complicated and likely less reliable.

Comment: @NikitaKalinin you're welcom

Comment: That's a really nice solution ! Do you think of an easy solution to keep the sectionning commands of the original document (i.e. sections, chapters, etc) ?
It seems that \Newassociation only works with environments, and I don't see how to do.

Comment: @mvienney i think yes, i'll try :-)

Comment: @mvienney please ask new question.

Comment: Already done here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355313/including-section-in-an-environment