# Get cleveref type, only

Tags: cleveref, xr

I am using the `xr` and `cleveref` packages to reference figures in another document, using the same figure and table numbers as the other document, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294097/56465). However, for non-floating figures and tables, I can't use the `\@captype` used in `\extref`. Therefore, I'd like to get the `cleveref` **type** of a given reference. However, I have been unable to find a technique for this.

Here's a MWE without `xr` and the external document (because I don't think those complications are important for this question, unless there's no way to extract the `cleveref` type).

Updated MWE (showing more precisely the problem):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extref}[1]{%
  \@namedef{the\@captype}{\ref{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{caption\label{fig:example}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.jpg}
\extref{fig:example}
\captionof{figure}{repeated}
\end{center}

Here is a reference: \cref{fig:example}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Updated MWE, now showing the use of `\extref`. I need to replace `\@captype` with something that extracts the cleveref type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `\namecref` is for:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.jpg}
\caption{caption\label{fig:example}}
\end{figure}

Here is a reference: \cref{fig:example}.

Now I want to know the label type: \namecref{fig:example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Getting the type proper, instead of the type name, as requested in the comments:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycreftype}[1]{%
  \cref@gettype{#1}{\@mytempvar}%
  \@mytempvar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
\caption{caption\label{fig:example}}
\end{figure}

Here is a reference: \cref{fig:example}.

Now I want to know the label type: \mycreftype{fig:example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I want the actual type and not the typeset version of the type. Is that what is returned?

Comment: @RicoPicone Mhm, I don't know any public interface for that, and I'm not sure there is one. It's probably viable to create some wrapper command that does it, but that's more than I can go for right now. With `zref-clever` it would be trivial, since it is exposed as a property, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: I'll take a look at `zref-clever` and see if my document will work with it without major surgery. I'll also update my MWE to include more explicitly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @RicoPicone Your question is clear, and the MWE very good. It is just that, as far as I know, this would be a non-trivial query for `cleveref`. But the information definitely exists and can be retrieved somehow. If you do get your document working with `zref-clever` and like it, all you need to get the type is `\zcref[ref=zc@type]{<label>}`.

Comment: @RicoPicone Oops, that would actually be `\zcref[ref=zc@type,noname]{<label>}`, or using `zref`, `\zref[zc@notype]{<label>}` (shorter, but no hyperlink).

Comment: @RicoPicone I took a look now, and found an internal auxiliary function of `cleveref` for the purpose. See edit.