# How avoid crossreftools package to handle theorem notes?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, crossreftools

Using `crossreftools` along with `hyperref` and `cleveref`, I can obtain cross-references, as shown in the output below, that include the names of "named theorems" or the note fields of ordinary theorems:

[image: Using crossreftools]
Here is the source:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{suffix}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\swapnumbers

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools} % <--- how eliminate?

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  headpunct={\bfseries\sffamily.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\bfseries\sffamily, 
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=namedthmstyle, title={}, numberlike=theorem]{namedtheorem}

\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

% --> HERE is where crossreftools is exploited <--
% Allow names in cross-reference to named theorems, etc.,...
% and optional argument names of theorems, etc:
\newcommand{\crefthm}[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\crtcrefcounter{#1}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%   
    }%
    [\crefthmname{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthm*[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\crtcrefcounter{#1}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }%
    [\crefthmname*{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
% For upper-casing, i.e., leave names as is:
\newcommand{\crefthmname}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\crtrefname{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthmname*[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}
\newcommand{\Crefthmname}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\crtrefname{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\Crefthmname*[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Math}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:plain}
    $a + b = b + a$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[basic arithmetic]\label{thm:simple}
    $1+1=2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Pythagorean theorem]\label{thm:pythag}
    The square upon the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals   
    the sum of the squares upon the other two sises.
\end{namedtheorem}

While \crefthm*{thm:simple} may seem simple,
the \crefthm{thm:pythag} is not.

Straightforward \verb!\cref! reference \cref{thm:plain} is OK, whereas \verb!\crefthm! gives: \crefthm{thm:plain}.

\end{document}
```

**Question:** How might one accomplish the same thing *without* using `crossreftools` (or recreating the relevant code from it) ?

Might the new LaTeX release 2023-11-01 `\NewProperty` / `RecordProperties` / `RefProperty` mechanism help here? (See LaTeX News, Issue 38, November 2023)

*Notes:*

1. In contrast to that MWE, in my actual document there are also "named propositions", "named lemmas", etc., and so the definitions of `\crefthm` and `\crefthm*` have additional alternatives included in the `\IfStrEqCase*` bodies.
2. The reason for asking the question is concern that `crossreftools` does not seem   to be actively maintained, its current version dating from 2020.

Comment: See, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692754/105447, on how to get the type directly from `cleveref` (which I think is the equivalent of `\crtcrefcounter`). For the anchor and name, you could probably rely on `refcount`. Off-topic: alas, your reasons for not wanting to use `crossreftools` seem a bit unfair. Just because a package has no recent update, it doesn't mean it is not working or not maintained. The latest version of `cleveref` itself is from 2018...

Comment: @gusbrs: I don't see how `refcount` can provide the names; I am trying to get the contents of the theorem note field, after all. (But your comment about package status is well-taken!)

Comment: Where do you think the name is stored? It is in the standard label, just like section names, captions, etc. Try `\getrefbykeydefault{thm:pythag}{name}{}`.

Comment: @gusbrs: Aha! I didn't know about that. Where does `\getrefbykeydefault` come from? I don't find it in the docs for `hyperref` or `cleveref`.

Comment: From `refcount`! ;-) I think `hyperref` (or `nameref`) loads it for you. Btw, I think you have everything you need to answer, but if you are interested in a `zref-clever` answer, I can provide one.

Comment: @gusbrs: OK, I found the documentation for `\getrefbykeydefault` in `refcount`. But I'd like to see, also, a `zref-clever` answer. Then I'll have 3 ways to approach this and can see which is the most appropriate for my needs.

Comment: Ok, I'll do so. It would be appreciated though if you provided a self answer using `\cref@gettype` and `refcount` (and accept it, because it is the answer to the actual question).

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit. And, yes, the new `ltproperties` is also an alternative for this.

Comment: I'm not seeing how `\getrefbykeydefault` can grab the "note" field (the optional argument from something like `\begin{theorem}[some description]`. I don't see in the `\refcount` any key for that.

Comment: murray, it's the same, it's in the `name` field (for `refcount`). The standard label has only 4 fields (actually five, but...): the ref, the page, the anchor, and the name/title. So it can only be in the name, and indeed that's where it is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll add a full answer then.

**Method 1**: Get the type/counter with `cleveref`'s `\cref@gettype` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692754/105447) and the rest with `refcount`'s `\getrefbykeydefault`:

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{suffix}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\swapnumbers

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
% \usepackage{crossreftools} % <--- how eliminate?

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  headpunct={\bfseries\sffamily.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=namedthmstyle, title={}, numberlike=theorem]{namedtheorem}

\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

% --> HERE is where crossreftools is exploited <--
% Allow names in cross-reference to named theorems, etc.,...
% and optional argument names of theorems, etc:
\newcommand{\mytemptype}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crefthm}[1]{%
  \cref@gettype{#1}{\mytemptype}%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\mytemptype}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }%
    [\crefthmname{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthm*[1]{%
  \cref@gettype{#1}{\mytemptype}%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\mytemptype}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }%
    [\crefthmname*{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
\makeatother
% For upper-casing, i.e., leave names as is:
\newcommand{\crefthmname}[1]{%
 \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthmname*[1]{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}}
\newcommand{\Crefthmname}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\Crefthmname*[1]{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Math}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:plain}
    $a + b = b + a$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[basic arithmetic]\label{thm:simple}
    $1+1=2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Pythagorean theorem]\label{thm:pythag}
    The square upon the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals
    the sum of the squares upon the other two sises.
\end{namedtheorem}

While \crefthm*{thm:simple} may seem simple,
the \crefthm{thm:pythag} is not.

Straightforward \verb!\cref! reference \cref{thm:plain} is OK, whereas \verb!\crefthm! gives: \crefthm{thm:plain}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Method 2**: Using the new `ltproperties` module:

(Proof of concept. I'd use method 1 myself, since there's no need to set any additional labels. The data is already there.)

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{suffix}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\swapnumbers

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
% \usepackage{crossreftools} % <--- how eliminate?

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  headpunct={\bfseries\sffamily.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=namedthmstyle, title={}, numberlike=theorem]{namedtheorem}

\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{namedtheorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

% --> HERE is where crossreftools is exploited <--
% Allow names in cross-reference to named theorems, etc.,...
% and optional argument names of theorems, etc:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__murray_inside_thm_bool % or any kind of boolean you prefer
\AddToHookWithArguments{label}{
  \bool_if:NT \l__murray_inside_thm_bool
    { \RecordProperties{#1.thm}{counter,title,target} }
}
\AddToHook{env/theorem/begin}{ \bool_set_true:N \l__murray_inside_thm_bool }
\AddToHook{env/namedtheorem/begin}{ \bool_set_true:N \l__murray_inside_thm_bool }
% Add any other theorem environments you use here...
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\crefthm}[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{counter}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }%
    [\crefthmname{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthm*[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{counter}}{%
    {namedtheorem}{\crefthmname*{#1}~(\ref{#1})}%
    }%
    [\crefthmname*{#1}~(\cref{#1})]%
}
% For upper-casing, i.e., leave names as is:
\newcommand{\crefthmname}[1]{%
 \hyperlink{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{target}}{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{title}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefthmname*[1]{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{title}}
\newcommand{\Crefthmname}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{target}}{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{title}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\Crefthmname*[1]{\RefProperty{#1.thm}{title}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Math}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:plain}
    $a + b = b + a$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[basic arithmetic]\label{thm:simple}
    $1+1=2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Pythagorean theorem]\label{thm:pythag}
    The square upon the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals
    the sum of the squares upon the other two sises.
\end{namedtheorem}

While \crefthm*{thm:simple} may seem simple,
the \crefthm{thm:pythag} is not.

Straightforward \verb!\cref! reference \cref{thm:plain} is OK, whereas \verb!\crefthm! gives: \crefthm{thm:plain}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Alternative**: Using `zref-clever`.

Since discussion in the comments suggested it might be of interest.

It turns out things are slightly simpler to set up, since `zref` makes it more straightforward to extract the references to different properties, and `zref-clever` allows for more flexibility with optional arguments, so we don't have to handle the hyperlink anchor manually. I also  leveraged `ltcmd` (formerly `xparse`) and `expl3` to also drop the dependencies on `xstring` and `suffix`.

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\swapnumbers

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{
  cap,
  noabbrev,
  countertype={namedtheorem=theorem},
}
\usepackage{zref-titleref,zref-counter}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  headpunct={\bfseries\sffamily.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\bfseries\sffamily,
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=namedthmstyle, title={}, numberlike=theorem]{namedtheorem}

% Note that this implementation requires that a single label be received as
% the mandatory argument of \zcrefthm.  But it is the same as with yours.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\zcrefthm}{sO{}m}{
  \tl_if_empty:eF { \zref@extractdefault {#3} { title } { } }
    {
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        { \zcref*[noname,ref=title]{#3} }
        { \zcref[noname,ref=title]{#3}  }
      \nobreakspace
    }
  \tl_if_eq:enTF
    { \zref@extractdefault {#3} { counter } { } } { namedtheorem }
    { (\zcref[noname,#2]{#3}) }
    { (\zcref[#2]{#3}) }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Math}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:plain}
    $a + b = b + a$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[basic arithmetic]\label{thm:simple}
    $1+1=2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Pythagorean theorem]\label{thm:pythag}
    The square upon the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals
    the sum of the squares upon the other two sises.
\end{namedtheorem}

While \zcrefthm*{thm:simple} may seem simple, the \zcrefthm{thm:pythag} is
not.

Straightforward \verb!\zcref! reference \zcref{thm:plain} is OK, whereas
\verb!\zcrefthm! gives: \zcrefthm{thm:plain}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `\zcrefthm*{thm:simple} may seem simple` is giving "While (Theorem 1.2) may seem simple". But in my original version using `crossreftools`, I had, and want to have, "While basic arithmetic (Theorem 1.2) may seem simple", which includes the contents of the note field of that theorem.

Comment: @murray Ah, I had missed that! I'm not really acquainted with `thmtools`... (In my defense, I was trying to fix the spurious space you get with `\crefthm{thm:plain}`). Anyway, hopefully fixed now.