# How to select a command based on the expansion of \Cref*?

Tags: cross-referencing, expl3, expansion, latex3, cleveref

(This is a somewhat of a continuation of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708026/207649) question of mine, which @egreg provided an easy solution to.)

In the following (slight variation of egreg's) MWE, three commands are defined. `\mylabel` creates `\label` (to be used by `\Cref` in the next two commands) and a `\RecordProperties` that will be used to record other info. Then there are `\mychapref` and `\mysecref` that produce the "conditional"/"relative" references.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\NewProperty{chapter}{now}{\bfseries??}{\Roman{chapter}}
\NewProperty{section}{now}{\bfseries??}{\arabic{section}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mylabel}{m}{%
    \label{#1}%
    \RecordProperties{#1@recProp}{chapter,section,target}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\NewDocumentCommand{\myref}{m}{
    % If \Cref*{#1} begins with "Chapter", then execute \mychapref{#1}.
    % If \Cref*{#1} begins with "Section", then execute \mysecref{#1}.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapref}{m}{
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \RefProperty{#1@recProp}{chapter} } { \Roman{chapter} } {
        % we are in the same chap
        this~chapter
    } {
        % in a diff chap
        \Cref{#1}
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mysecref}{m}{
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \RefProperty{#1@recProp}{chapter} } { \Roman{chapter} } {
        % we are in the same chap
        \str_if_eq:eeTF{ \RefProperty{#1@recProp}{section} } { \arabic{section}} {
            % in the same sec
            this~section
            } {
            %same chap diff sec
            \Cref{#1}
            }
        }
    
    {
        % in a diff chap
        \Cref{#1},\nobreakspace Chapter\nobreakspace\RefProperty{#1@recProp}{chapter}
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}\mylabel{CHAP: I}
    \mychapref{CHAP: I}
    
    \section{abc}\mylabel{SEC: I.1}
    
    \mysecref{SEC: I.1}
    
    \section{efg}
    
    \mysecref{SEC: I.1}
    
    
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    
    \mychapref{CHAP: I}
    
    \mysecref{SEC: I.1}
    
\end{document}
```

**What is wanted:** I want to "combine" `\mychapref` and `\mysecref` in a command `\myref` as described in the comment above. However, I [came across](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/381513/207649) the fact that `\Cref*` is not expandable and hence I can't assign it to string variables using `\str_set:Ne`, or try `\exp_args:Ne`, and then procees with the logic.

Is there a way to implement what is intended here?

---

**Edit:**

So, I tried to define `\myref` via `\mycreftype` that @gusbrs defines [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692754/207649), like so:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\myref}{m}{
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \mychapref{#1} } { chapter } { \mychapref{#1} } {}
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \mycreftype{#1} } { section } { \mysecref{#1} } {}
}
```

However, running the MWE (with just the above and @gusbrs' definition of `\mycreftype` added to the preamble, along with replacing `\mychapref{CHAP: I}` with `\myref{CHAP: I}`), I get error messages, the first being

```
Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. \myref{CHAP: I}
```

Any help?

Comment: You already know `\cref` is not expandable, and the very link you provided, also shows that `crossreftools` has  a simplified expandable one `\crtcref`, which you could use. But, in your case, you might prefer to get the type directly with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692754/105447.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also store the `counter` property in your `\RecordProperties{#1@recProp}` call, then use it to assume the type.

Comment: Brilliant options! The `type` best solves my case, for I plan to have theorem environments as well. Thanks tons!

Comment: I must say I do agree with @egreg in that this style of referencing is somewhat jarring... Anyway, and off-topic, you could get away from needing `\mylabel` by just setting your properties on the `label` hook (with `\AddToHookWithArguments`).

Comment: @gusbrs Ooh, thanks! I will update my code to incorporate this `\AddToHookWithArguments`. Btw, something is not working when I incorporated your `\mycreftype` in my MWE to define `\myref`. I have edited my question. Can you have a look? Many thanks!

Comment: It's really simple, `\mycreftype` itself is non expandable since it performs an assignment, but you can use the assignment it does to store the value of interest in a variable, and then compare that. I'll add an answer, it may be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the procedure at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692754/105447 to retrieve the reference type, and than compare that.

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\NewProperty{chapter}{now}{\textbf{??}}{\Roman{chapter}}
\NewProperty{section}{now}{\textbf{??}}{\arabic{section}}

\AddToHookWithArguments{label}{%
  \RecordProperties{#1@recProp}{chapter,section,target}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\tl_new:N \l_mytempvar_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\myref}{m}{
  \cref@gettype {#1} { \l_mytempvar_tl }
  \str_case:VnF \l_mytempvar_tl
    {
      % If type is "chapter", then execute \mychapref{#1}.
      { chapter } { \mychapref{#1} }
      % If type is "section", then execute \mysecref{#1}.
      { section } { \mysecref{#1} }
    }
    {
      % Anything else, just \Cref
      \Cref {#1}
    }
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapref}{m}{
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \RefProperty { #1 @recProp } { chapter } } { \Roman{chapter} }
    {
      % we are in the same chap
      this~chapter
    }
    {
      % in a diff chap
      \Cref {#1}
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mysecref}{m}{
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \RefProperty { #1@recProp } { chapter } } { \Roman{chapter} }
    {
      % we are in the same chap
      \str_if_eq:eeTF{ \RefProperty { #1 @recProp } { section } } { \arabic{section} }
        {
          % in the same sec
          this~section
        }
        {
          %same chap diff sec
          \Cref {#1}
        }
    }
    {
      % in a diff chap
      \Cref {#1},\nobreakspace Chapter\nobreakspace
      \RefProperty { #1 @recProp } { chapter }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\label{CHAP:I}

\mychapref{CHAP:I}\par
\myref{CHAP:I}

\section{abc}
\label{SEC:I.1}

\mysecref{SEC:I.1}\par
\myref{SEC:I.1}

\section{efg}

\mysecref{SEC:I.1}\par
\myref{SEC:I.1}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\mychapref{CHAP:I}\par
\myref{CHAP:I}\par
\mysecref{SEC:I.1}\par
\myref{SEC:I.1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I went through the [documentation](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-code.pdf) for adding hooks. The impression that I got is to use `cmd/label/after` rather than simply `label` in `\AddToHookWithArguments`. However, trying to do so raises errors. Can you clarify? (I really appreciate your patience with me!)

Comment: What I understood was that generic hooks for commands (Sec 3.1.2 [here](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-code.pdf)) are of the form `cmd/<name>/before` or `cmd/<name>/after`.

Comment: @Atom Well, the answer tells you how to do it. It works. And then you ask me why when you do it differently you get an error? That's unfair. ;-) Anyway, the answer is simple, the `label` is the the argument to `\label`, how do you expect to use that value in `\AddToHook{cmd/label/after}` if it does not pass the argument around? Check `texdoc ltnews37` for more info on the `label` hook.

Comment: Okay, I won't take further of your time.  But I really wish I had a TeXnician like you with whom I could talk and clarify my things. Nevertheless, many thanks for such great help! Oh, you mentioned about the `label` hook documentation! Just looked and my questions are dissolved.